# How to find public ip for a freebsd system

Tags: freebsd, ip

Can someone tell me a command that will find my external ip for a freebsd 10 system.

Comment: What do you mean with external IP? Is your system connected to the internet directly without ppp or a router?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I use `wtfismyip.com` which returns pure text and does not need parsing:

```
$ wget -qO - http://wtfismyip.com/text
123.456.78.9
```

User Steve Wills pointed out in a comment that the command `fetch` is installed by default on FreeBSD so it might be a better choice instead of `wget`.

Comment: The `fetch` command is part of the OS, unlike wget, so it's always there, might be better to use it.

Comment: `fetch -q http://wtfismyip.com/text ; cat ./text;`

Answer (score 1):

Try from the CLI

```
 wget checkip.dyndns.org:80 -O - -o /dev/null | cut -d" " -f6 | sed 's/<\/body><\/html>//'
```

or

```
 wget 216.146.39.70:80 -O - -o /dev/null | cut -d" " -f6 | sed 's/<\/body><\/html>//'
```

if you do not wish to call the DNSs.

You can always load the following URL, *www.whatismyipaddress.com* in your browser; this is but one of many different sites returning your IP, among them is also *speedtest.net*.